# How can I specify where to put values for a GET request in a HTML form?

Tags: html, mit-scratch, google-sites-2016

### Context

I'm making a scratch project, with a sign in page on google sites. I'm using forkphorus so that I can manipulate the output of the username block. I have built a script in my scratch project that seperates out the username string (which is specified by a URL parameter) into variables (lists actually, but I don't want to overcomplicate things). I won't go into much detail, but say the username string was this:

`username%3Ahello%20password%3Aworld`

A script in the project would decode the URL encoded text into this:

`username:hello password:world`

And then username would be set to hello and password to world.

---

### The problem

However, I want this to work with an HTML form embedded on my google site. When I use the code below, it takes me to [this URL](https://forkphorus.github.io/app.html?uname=hello&pword=world)<sup>1</sup>, wheras I want to go to [this URL](https://forkphorus.github.io/app.html?id=myprojectid&username=uname%3Ahello%20pword%3Aworld)<sup>2</sup>.

#### URLs

<sup>1</sup>`https://forkphorus.github.io/app.html?uname=hello&pword=world`

<sup>2</sup>`https://forkphorus.github.io/app.html?id=myprojectid&username=uname%3Ahello%20pword%3Aworld`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="https://forkphorus.github.io/app.html?id=myprojectid">

<label for="uname">Username:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="uname" name="uname" value="hello"><br>
<label for="pword">Password:</label><br>
<input type="password" id="pword" name="pword" value="world"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Log in">

</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

---

### My question

How can I change/add to my code to get to my desired URL by entering the appropriate values into the form?

Comment: To attach the id with the query, use something like `<input name="id" type="hidden" value="myprojectid">` somewhere in the form

Comment: Thanks - any idea how I could compile the two other inputs into the username parameter with my custom seperator?

Comment: You might want to add a custom listener for when the form is submitted and process that data from there.

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me - my knowledge of html and web development is pretty intermittent.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom form submit logic (the Stackoverflow CORS policy will prevent the submit action from doing anything however it should work anywhere else):

```js
document.querySelector(".info-form").addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  event.stopPropagation();

  const username = encodeURIComponent(document.querySelector("#uname").value);
  const password = encodeURIComponent(document.querySelector("#pword").value);
  location.href = `https://forkphorus.github.io/app.html?id=myprojectid&username=${username}%3Ahello%20pword%3A${password}`;
});
```

```html
<form class="info-form" action="#">

  <label for="uname">Username:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="uname" value="hello" required><br>
  <label for="pword">Password:</label><br>
  <input type="password" id="pword" value="world" required><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Log in">

</form>
```